# What is the location a dynamically loaded assembly should be , and how to refer it, in C#?

Tags: c#

Here what i am looking for is where should i expect/suggest the dynamic dll will be present?

should i use the location CurrentDirectory+AssemblyName for loading?

or should i be using the location Assembly.CodeBase property?

i am trying to use the Assembly.LoadFile(path).

Basically i want to load that assembly only if that is added to the solution.

it is supplied alongside my application , not a standard .net dll

Comment: can you be more specific? what do you want to load? something supplied alongside your application (like a plugin) or do you want to load a standard .net dll?

Comment: Is there a reason why you wouldn't use Assembly.Load(assemblyName) and place your assembly somewhere within the probing path or the GAC?  More info on what you are trying to do would help.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to do this is to simply ensure that the dll is in your probing path (search) and (as Tuzo noets), use `Assembly.Load`. If you want to load a dll from *outside* your path (and not in the GAC) then it gets tricky. There is `Assembly.LoadFile` / `Assembly.LoadFrom`, but then you need to worry about the [load-context](http://blogs.msdn.com/suzcook/archive/2003/09/19/loadfile-vs-loadfrom.aspx); you can quickly find that you get problems with the dlls that your dynamic code uses.

Another way of simplifying things is to use a separate `AppDomain`; this new `AppDomain` can have a different base/bin - allowing you to bring in the right dlls (and unload it when you want). You can either use `CreateInstanceAndUnwrap` (which establishes a remoting hook between two `AppDomain`s, using a `MarshalByRefObject` proxy), or (for one-shot use) you can simply execute the new `AppDomain` with `ExecuteAssembly`.

I covered a range of these points in [GAC, Assembly Resolution , and all that Jazz](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/07/gac-assembly-resolution-and-all-that.html)

Answer (score 0):

I should be using CodeBase property of the CurrentExecuting directory to get the location,
because the CurrentDirectory could be changed at any point using the 
System.Environment.CurrentDirectory = somelocation.

Comment: Hey Naresh, a bit off topic - can you undelete this question and answer it with how you resolved it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40135212/service-fabric-application-upgrade-fails-whereas-new-deployment-works (I'll delete this comment as soon as you do).